# Redacting phone numbers

Tags: regex

I need to hide phone numbers and other contact details in user generated content to make possible an online introduction service. Input is random classifieds style adverts, therefore I'd be looking to replace anything that looks like a phone number (e.g.: string of 3 or more numbers) with (phone number hidden), and also perhaps remove some exotic notations of e-mail addresses.

What is the best way to do this?

```
def redact_contact_details(s):
    # redact phone numbers
    ...
    # redact e-mail addresses
    ...
    # redact web addresses
    ...
```

Edit: Some of what I learned and coded to solve this type of problem is out and open source https://github.com/fmalina/django-reveal

Comment: What country?  Or do you simply want to match ANY possible phone number?

Comment: It depends very much on what the user content will be like. E.g. `140370` could be my birthday (I just forget the dots) or is it a phone number or maybe the number of whatever I have achieved?

Comment: I ended up with something much more elegant, check if the input contains a lot of consecutive digits in a short shingle (phone) or something on a blacklist ('@', '[at]', '.com', '.co.uk') and flag it for the admin to have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, to replace three or more digits with three dots in string `s`:

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'\d{3,}', '...', s)
```

"Exotic notations of e-mail addresses" is hard for me to parse; maybe you mean s/thing like

```
s = re.sub(r'[\w.]+@[\w.]+', '<email redacted>', s)
```

Comment: Thank you, short and sweet, now just something that will nicely hide sloppy human web addresses. Hungry, but intelligent

Answer (score 1):

By web addresses I'm guessing you mean URLs. You could create an array that contains all possible domains `(".ca",".com",".uk"....)`. You can then run a regex replace on any 'word' that contains one of the domains.

To do the replacement you can use Alec Martelli's code and instead of putting the '@' in your replacement put the join of the array of domains. The join function is explained on [this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/odbchelper_join.html) site.

If in perl I would do the match like :

```
my $domainsString = join("|", @arrayOfPossibleDomains);
$s =~ s/\w+[$domainString]\w+/......./g;
```

Comment: Yup, just what I needed to hide those "web addresses".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function that just replaces any alphanumeric character with a "." or any other character you want.

For example:

```
function HideInput($input) {
    $input = preg_replace("([a-zA-Z0-9])", "*", $input);
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is to actually **find** that part in the user submitted content. Every text consists of alphanumeric characters.